# http error 403.14 - forbidden visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I work a project in visual studio 2019. A asp.net i received an error code while working on my project. I have looked at some solutions to solve the problem. I've tried two methods, but they also have problems. I need to solve it with some commands in the ISS Manager or via cmd. I also get the following error when I try to solve it via cmd. "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

CMD scripts:

> C:\Program Files\IIS Express

> appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true

What exactly should i do now? How can I reach the solution in the fastest and simplest way?

Comment: To execute a command-line program where the path contains spaces, you need to enclose the path in quotes: `cd "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\"`

Comment: You have a HTTP error.  A HTTP connection has client and server code.  The 403.14 error is generated on the server code while processing the request.  Forbidden usually means the application does not have the credentials to perform an operation on the server.  A HTTP server only has GUEST privilege's by default when a connection is made.  You can start the HTTP service with ADMIN rights but that is dangerous because it can open a back door for hackers to attack the server.